# Listening to classes in Java

Tags: java

Here is code that I took from a book:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class RandGen extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton genButton;
    private JButton seedButton;
    private JLabel randLabel;
    private JTextField seedText;
    private int randNumber;

    public RandGen() {
        super("Random number generator");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        randNumber = 215;
        randLabel = new JLabel("***   " + randNumber + " ***");

        genButton = new JButton("Generate");
        genButton.addActionListener(this);
        seedButton = new JButton("Set seed");
        seedButton.addActionListener(this);
        seedText = new JTextField();
        seedText.setColumns(10);
        seedText.setText("" + randNumber);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(seedText);
        getContentPane().add(seedButton);
        getContentPane().add(genButton);
        getContentPane().add(randLabel);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void nextRand() {
        if (randNumber % 2 == 0)
            randNumber = randNumber / 2;
        else
            randNumber = randNumber * 3 + 1;

        setRandNumber(randNumber);
    }

    private void setRandNumber(int randnumber) {
        this.randNumber = randNumber;
        randLabel.setText("*** " + this.randNumber + " ***");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(genButton))
            this.nextRand();

        if (e.getSource().equals(seedButton)) {
            randNumber = Integer.parseInt(seedText.getText());
            setRandNumber(randNumber);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RandGen frame = new RandGen();
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the `RandGen` class is "listening" to some changes that appear in `seedButton` and `genButton`, and when that happens, apply the `actionPerformed` and check the source of the event. I don't understand what happens with `seedButton` and `genButton`.

Which method do they need to apply in order to inform the listener that something was changed?

Comment: You really need to format your code better to make it easier for us to read. More persons would take the time to read it if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons are registered for the listener with a call to addActionListener.

```
  genButton.addActionListener(this);
```

At this line, the genButton is being registered so that if the action is triggered then"this" object will handle the event. This referes to the current instance of the class. In this class you will find the actionPerformed method that will be executed on the action of the button.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I miss basic thing. "this" is listening to genButton. So if something change in genButton, then "this" know about it and apply the actionPerformed (in his class). But I didn't get what happen in genButton? What does it mean that something is happened in genButton? How genButton inform it to "this"? What am I missing?

Comment: I got it. The class genButton is apply the "actionPerformed" with event that It make.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the implementation of the `JButton` class to call the `actionPerformed()` method of all registered listeners when the button is pressed - you don't have to implement that part. Note that this will happen on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is that the actionPerformed() call is more like a callback.

This line registered your class with the object that generates the event.

```
seedButton.addActionListener(this);
```

It tells the seedButton to call your actionPerformed() method when it detects an event.